# saving ObservableCollection<MyClass> to SQLite or similar, Xamarin Forms

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I'm having multiple ObservableCollections in my app, which I would like to save, edit and so on. But since they're a collection of my own type of class, SQLite doesn't recognizes them. What would be the best way to save theses? Or what am I doing wrong.

Sort of looks something like this:

In my App: (Of course there's more code inside)

```html
public partial class App : Application 
{ 
  static MyDatabase database; 
  
  public static MyDatabase Database 
  { 
    get 
    { 
      if (database == null) 
      { 
        database = new MyDatabase(DependencyService.Get
<IFileHelper>().GetLocalFilePath("MyListSQLite.db3")); 
      } 
      return database; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

MyDatabase:

```js
public class MyDatabase
{
  readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

  public MyDatabase(string dbPath)
  {
    database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
    database.CreateTableAsync<MyClass>().Wait();
  }

  public Task<List<MyClass>> GetItemsAsync()
  {
    return database.Table<MyClass>().ToListAsync();
  }

 public Task<MyClass> GetItemAsync(int id)
 {
  return database.Table<MyClass>().Where(i => i.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
 }

 public Task<int> SaveItemAsync(MyClass item)
 {
  if (item.ID != 0)
  {
   return database.UpdateAsync(item);
  }
  else
  {
   return database.InsertAsync(item);
  }
 }

 public Task<int> DeleteItemAsync(MyClass item)
 {
  return database.DeleteAsync(item);
 }

}
```

MyClass:

```html
public class MyClass : ObservableCollection<MyOtherClass>
{ 
  [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement] 
  public int ID { get; set; } 
}
```

MyOtherClass:

```html
public class MyOtherClass : BindableObject
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }


        public static readonly BindableProperty ListNbrProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("ListNbr", typeof(int), typeof(MyOtherClass), default(int));

  public int ListNbr
  {
   get { return (int)GetValue(ListNbrProperty); }
   set { SetValue(ListNbrProperty, value); }
  }

        public bool IsMaster { get; set; }

  public static readonly BindableProperty ResizedPathProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("ResizedPath", typeof(String), typeof(MyOtherClass), default(String));

  public String ResizedPath
  {
            get { return (String)GetValue(ResizedPathProperty); }
   set { SetValue(ResizedPathProperty, value); }
  }
...
}
```

Comment: I guess this is not the best approach to do that. Seems like you want to save the MyOtherClass objects - once your collection doesn't have a reason to live except to present your objects (just for show or proccess something) -  so you can do this using `database.InsertAll` or `database.UpdateAll` at your Database class.

Answer (score 1):

In most of our applications, for complex objects, we simply serialise them into Json so that they can be stored as strings (In your case NVarChar(MAX) ?). We don't always use SQL, sometimes we use the native projects own storage mechanisms (I.E. NSUserDefaults for iOS)

`using Newtonsoft.Json;`

```
    public static async Task<bool> CacheList (ObservableList<string> MyList)
    {
        try
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyList);

            // you dont need to encrypt the string, but we deal with some 
            // sensitive data so we have a seperate cryptography class that handles this.

            var EncryptedJson = Cryptography.Crypto.Encrypt(json, Key);

            // Now you have your serialised object simply store it into your database using whatever method you usually user

            [Store to SQLdatabase Code goes here]

            return await Task.FromResult(true);
        }
        catch (Exception genEx)
        {
            var Error = genEx.Message;
            return await Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }
```

And to retrieve it:

```
    public static async Task<ObservableList<string>> RetrieveList (string key)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve your json string from your sql database

            [retrieve from SQLdatabase Code goes here - returns EncryptedJson]

            // In our case we decrypt it
            var DecryptedJson = Cryptography.Crypto.Decrypt(EncryptedJson, Key);
            var DeSerialisedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableList<string>>(DecryptedJson);

            return await Task.FromResult(DeSerialisedData ?? new ObservableList<string>());

        }
        catch (Exception genEx)
        {
            var Error = genEx.Message;
            return await Task.FromResult(new ObservableList<string>());
        }
    }
```

The above isn't a copy and paste and it'll work example, it's really more a high level concept that we use in our applications.

Comment: Nice, was thinking about json as well, and didn't know which one was the best approach since I have no experience with these. Just made `MyClass` to get an id to each `ObservableCollection`, but is it possible to do like you've done above but with `<ObservableList<MyOtherClass>` ?

Comment: Yep absolutely, the json SerializeObject method will break down complex objects into their properties in an accurate json representation, so go nuts. =)